# "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" error when providing list of lambda functions to pandas' pivot_table method?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have been using pandas.pivot_table to aggregate over my dataframes by giving the aggfunc param a list of functions (`[np.mean, np.std]` for example). Now I want to wrap those functions so that they only operate on the first half of a provided column, doing something like:

```
new_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values=feature_cols, index=id_cols, aggfunc=[lambda x: np.mean(x[:len(x)//2]), lambda y: np.std(y[:len(y)//2])])
```

Which spits out the error:

```
pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

However, `new_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values=feature_cols, index=id_cols, aggfunc=[np.mean,np.std])` works just fine.

I believe I may be misunderstanding how `pivot_table` passes the array-like to the aggregate functions or how lambdas work in general.

Would like to either fix this or learn about a better way to wrap functions in python. I do not want to use a `def` defined function for every function in the list I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc of pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html): When you provide a list of functions to aggregate, the columns will be  hierarchical, and the top level are the function names (inferred from the function objects themselves). With two `lambda` functions, the two names will be the same. And that's where your problem come from.

Well I would be OK using `def` to give the function a name. But if you really want to use `lambda`, maybe using `groupby` and `agg` instead:

```
new_df = df.groupby(id_col).agg([('half-mean',lambda x:np.mean(x[:len(x)//2])),('half-std',lambda x:np.std(x[:len(x)//2]))])
```